# Using shortcut for imported library in Angular

Tags: angular, tsconfig, angular-library

I had Core and Shared modules in my project which were separated into an external library.

I had references to the @core and @shared folders using a few shortcuts in tsconfig.ts:

```
"@core": ["src/app/@core"],
"@core/*": ["src/app/@core/*"],
"@shared": ["src/app/@shared"],
"@shared/*": ["src/app/@shared/*"],
```

So my imports could simply be:

```
import { SomeThing } from '@shared/modals'
```

---

Now that I created a separated lib, build, packed and imported the tarball file, how can I keep the path shortcuts, simply updating them to point to the new location?

I can import stuff using 'core-project/core', but if I add that path in the shortcuts, it fails to find it.

```
//Works:
import { SomeThing } from 'core-project/shared/modals'

//Fails:
"@shared": ["core-project/shared"],
import { SomeThing } from '@shared/modals'

//Also Fails:
"@shared": ["node_modules/core-project/src/shared"],
```

---

Working, but is there a better way?

"@shared": ["node_modules/core-project/shared"],

This is working, but is there a proper way to import?

Comment: the simplest way is to just package the lib with the same alias i.e. `@shared/modals`

Comment: Ahhh, that's smart. Thanks!